# Using Helvetica Neue in Cordova Hybrid Apps

Tags: ios, cordova, mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

Helvetica Neue is the default font in iOS 7/8. When building hybrid apps, how do you include Helvetica Neue as the font?

It does not seem to be a free font. Or are most hybrid app developers pulling an open source version of Helvetica Neue from a CDN?

Answer (score 1):

Helvetica Neue is not a free font sadly, and isn't licensed by standard on Android. It gets pretty expensive if you want to embed it within your app outside of iOS (see [Linotype](http://www.linotype.com/1266/neueHelvetica-family.html))

I guess you have a few options:

- "Roboto" was first included in Ice Cream Sandwich, and looks very similar - comparison [here](http://theunderstatement.com/post/11645166791/roboto-vs-helvetica). So you could include this in your CSS stack.
- Use a similar open source font like Open Sans ([Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans#charset)) and embed the TTF file into your app.
- Use a CSS stack that starts with Helvetica Neue, and works its way backwards to less nice fonts, depending on what platform the hybrid app is running on - i.e. [this stack](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/better-helvetica/). You could add Roboto earlier in the stack if you like it...